# shortest string length show in main method but not when placed in another method

Tags: java, string, arraylist, methods

This is the code

```
Package labone;
import java.util.*;

public class LabOne {

static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("type\n 1: Exercise 1 'People's names'\n '");
    int choose = reader.nextInt();
    switch(choose) {
        case 1 :
            PeopleNames();
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("invaild choice");
            break;
    }         
}

  public static void PeopleNames() {                
       //////// PEOPLES NAMES ////////       
  System.out.println("Enter names of people, if done enter 'done'");
    String Name = reader.nextLine();
    while(!"done".equals(Name)){ //if user type done exit from adding names
        names.add(Name); // otherwise add names
        Name = reader.nextLine();  //reads what user entered
    }
    //User typed 'done' and it displays the names in the arraylist
    PrintArray(); // method

    //Find Longest String
  int largestString = names.get(0).length(); 
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++){
        if(names.get(i).length() > largestString) {
            largestString = names.get(i).length();
            index = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(names.get(index) + " is the longest name and the length is " + largestString);

    //Find Shortest String
   int shortestString = names.get(0).length();
    int index1 = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++){
        if(names.get(i).length() < shortestString) {
            shortestString = names.get(i).length();
            index1 = i;
        } 
    }
     System.out.println(names.get(index1) + " is the shortest name and the length is  " + shortestString); 

     //Find the Average of all the Strings
     double num = names.size(); //number of elements in arraylist(size())
     double length =-1; 
     for(String str : names){
         length = length + str.length(); //sum of the lengths in the arraylist 
     }   
     length = length + names.size()-1;   
      num = length/num;    //divide the sum with the size()
      System.out.println("The average length of the names in the list: "+num);
}


 //Method to view arrayList ( names )
public static void PrintArray() {
    System.out.println("---------");
    for(String Name : names){
        System.out.println(Name);
    }

  }
   }
```

**Result**
run:
type
 1: Exercise 1 'People's names'
1
Enter names of people, if done enter 'done'
ashmeen
blom
done

ashmeen is the longest name and the length is 7
 is the shortest name and the length is  0  ***DOES NOT GIVE ANSWER***
The average length of the names in the list: 4.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)

when i place the code in the main method it gives the answer of the shortest string and longest string, however, when the code is placed in PeopleNames method, it only shows the longest string but it does not show the shortest string.

Comment: Can you describe what steps you have taken to debug this code yourself? "It works in the main method" can be a bit vague.

Comment: I have added the result.

Comment: when i place the code in the main method it gives the answer of the shortest string and longest string, however, when the code is placed in PeopleNames method, it only shows the longest string but it does not show the shortest string.

Comment: @AshmeenCloete make sure your array does not have the value `""` (empty string) in it. That could cause issues with finding the shortest name.

Comment: it doesn't have, but i'll double check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `reader.nextLine()` to `reader.next()` as `nextLine()` function is adding one **empty string** to the arrayList as first member. the code will look as below:

```
    String Name = reader.next();
    while(!"done".equals(Name)){ //if user type done exit from adding names
        names.add(Name); // otherwise add names
        Name = reader.next();  //reads what user entered
    }
```

Regards.